# Remove elements in slice

Tags: go, slice

I am complete newbie in Golang, I am trying to remove elements in one slice based on the elements in another slice.
e.g.

input slice : `urlList := []string{"test", "abc", "def", "ghi"}`

elements to remove slice : `remove := []string{"abc", "test"}`

expected output slice : `urlList := []string{"def", "ghi"}`

This is what I tried.

```
func main() {

    urlList := []string{"test", "abc", "def", "ghi"}
    remove := []string{"abc", "test"}
loop:
    for i, url := range urlList {
        for _, rem := range remove {
            if url == rem {
                urlList = append(urlList[:i], urlList[i+1:]...)
                continue loop
            }
        }
    }
    for _, v := range urlList {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

But it's not working as I expected. I don't know what I am missing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that when you remove an element from the original list, all subsequent elements are *shifted*. But the `range` loop doesn't know that you changed the underlying slice and will increment the index as usual, even though in this case it shouldn't because then you **skip** an element.

And since the `remove` list contains 2 elements which are **right next to each other** in the original list, the second one (`"abc"` in this case) will not be checked and will not be removed.

One possible solution is not to use `range` in the outer loop, and when you remove an element, you manually decrease the index **`i--`** because continuing with the next iteration it will get auto-incremented:

```
urlList := []string{"test", "abc", "def", "ghi"}
remove := []string{"abc", "test"}

loop:
for i := 0; i < len(urlList); i++ {
    url := urlList[i]
    for _, rem := range remove {
        if url == rem {
            urlList = append(urlList[:i], urlList[i+1:]...)
            i-- // Important: decrease index
            continue loop
        }
    }
}

fmt.Println(urlList)
```

**Output:**

```
[def ghi]
```

**Note:**

Since the outer loop contains nothing after the inner loop, you can replace the label+continue with a simple `break`:

```
urlList := []string{"test", "abc", "def", "ghi"}
remove := []string{"abc", "test"}

for i := 0; i < len(urlList); i++ {
    url := urlList[i]
    for _, rem := range remove {
        if url == rem {
            urlList = append(urlList[:i], urlList[i+1:]...)
            i-- // Important: decrease index
            break
        }
    }
}

fmt.Println(urlList)
```

Try it on [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/aP7wta6wfx).

**Alternative**

An alternative to this would be for the outer loop to go downward, so no need to manually decrease (or increase) the index variable because the shifted elements are not affected (already processed due to the downward direction).

Comment: downward loop is more efficient

Comment: @VKS Yes. And it is mentioned at the end of the answer.

Comment: If only go had a keyword corresponding to Perl's `redo` (like `continue` except it doesn't re-execute the loop test or increment) then the code would be correct after replacing `continue` with `redo`. As it is... well, there's always `goto` :)

Comment: You should probably nil the element before deleting it. Otherwise there could be a memory leak https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it is simpler to create a new slice, that only contains your desired elements, for example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    urlList := []string{"test", "abc", "def", "ghi"}
    remove := []string{"abc", "test"}

    new_list := make([]string, 0)

    my_map := make(map[string]bool, 0)
    for _, ele := range remove {
        my_map[ele] = true
    }

    for _, ele := range urlList {
        _, is_in_map := my_map[ele]
        if is_in_map {
            fmt.Printf("Have to ignore : %s\n", ele)
        } else {
            new_list = append(new_list, ele)    
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(new_list)

}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/aYATElNwSP)

Result:

```
Have to ignore : test
Have to ignore : abc
[def ghi]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful when modifying a slice while iterating over it.

Here's a common way to remove elements from a slice by compacting the data at the same time as iterating over it.

It also uses a map rather than a slice for excluded elements, which gives efficiency when the number of excluded items is large.

`Exclude` updates `xs` in place, which is why a pointer argument is used. An alternative would be to update the backing array of `xs`, but to return the slice from the function in the same way that the built-in `append` works.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func Exclude(xs *[]string, excluded map[string]bool) {
    w := 0
    for _, x := range *xs {
        if !excluded[x] {
            (*xs)[w] = x
            w++
        }
    }
    *xs = (*xs)[:w]
}

func mapFromSlice(ex []string) map[string]bool {
    r := map[string]bool{}
    for _, e := range ex {
        r[e] = true
    }
    return r
}

func main() {
    urls := []string{"test", "abc", "def", "ghi"}
    remove := mapFromSlice([]string{"abc", "test"})
    Exclude(&urls, remove)
    fmt.Println(urls)
}
```

This code is O(N+M) in run-time where N is the length of `urls` and M is the length of `remove`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these functions:

```
func main() {
  array := []string{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}
  a = StringSliceDelete(a, 2) // delete "C"
  fmt.Println(a) // print: [A, B, D E]
}

//IntSliceDelete function
func IntSliceDelete(slice []int, index int) []int {
   copy(slice[index:], slice[index+1:])
   new := slice[:len(slice)-1]
   return new
}

//StringSliceDelete function
func StringSliceDelete(slice []string, index int) []string {
    copy(slice[index:], slice[index+1:])
    new := slice[:len(slice)-1]
    return new
}

// ObjectSliceDelete function
func ObjectSliceDelete(slice []interface{}, index int) []interface{} {
    copy(slice[index:], slice[index+1:])
    new := slice[:len(slice)-1]
    return new
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of index:

```golang
//RemoveElements delete the element of the indexes contained in j of the data in input
func RemoveElements(data []string, j []int) []string {
    var newArray []string
    var toAdd bool = true
    var removed int = 0
    //sort.Ints(j)
    for i := 0; i < len(data); i++ {
        for _, k := range j {
            // if k < i || k > i {
            //  break
            // } else
            if i == k {
                toAdd = false
                break
            }
        }
        if toAdd {
            newArray = append(newArray, data[i])
            removed++
        }
        toAdd = true
    }
    return newArray
}
```

Comment can be removed for increase performance when the slice is not so big (sort time)

Answer (score 0):

Try it

https://go.dev/play/p/CKvGWl7vG4_V

```
elements := []string{"one", "two", "three", "four"}
needToRemove := []string{"one", "four"}

newSlice := remove(elements, needToRemove) // []string{"two", "three"}


func remove(slice, elements []string) []string {
    out := []string{}
    bucket := map[string]bool{}

    for _, element := range slice {
        if !inSlice(elements, element) && !bucket[element] {
            out = append(out, element)
            bucket[element] = true
        }
    }

    return out
}

func inSlice(slice []string, elem string) bool {
    for _, i := range slice {
        if i == elem {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```