# How do I remove a field from a model in Google App Engine with Go?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

What is the Go equivalent of Python `delattr` or Java: `Entity.removeProperty`?

I am trying to remove a property from the datastore as described here:
[removing deleted properties from the datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema#removing-deleted-properties-from-the-datastore)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to remove a property from a saved entity, you have to load it first, and save it again with the same key but without the property you want to remove. If you want to remove a property from all saved entities (of a kind), you have to load and save each one-by-one. (Of course you may use other means like [`Query`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference?#Query)'s and [`datastore.PutMulti()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference?#PutMulti) to query and save multiple entities.)

You can remove a property from a saved entity in basically 2 ways:

#### Using 2 structs:

You can use 2 structs: your *old* model and the *new* model (without the property you want to remove):

```
type Old struct {
    Name     string `datastore:"name"`
    Removeme string `datastore:"removeme"`
}

type New struct {
    Name     string `datastore:"name"`
}
```

And load the entity and re-save it (with the same key):

```
c := appengine.NewContext(r)
// Constructing the key, for example:
k := datastore.NewKey(c, "Entity", "stringID", 0, nil)

e := new(Old)
if err = datastore.Get(c, key, e); err != nil {
    // Datastore error.
    return
}

e2 := New{e.Name}
if _, err = datastore.Put(c, k, &e2); err != nil {
    // Datastore error
}
```

#### Using `PropertyList`

Or you can use the [`datastore.PropertyList`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference?#PropertyList) to load any entity into it.

It's basically just a slice of [`Property`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference?#Property)'s:

```
type PropertyList []Property
```

Remove the property (or properties) you want to delete from this slice, and re-save it with the same key.

Basically the steps are the same: load an entity with a key, remove unwanted properties, and resave it (with the same key).

**Remove an element from a slice:**

To delete the element from slice `a` at index `i`:

```
a = append(a[:i], a[i+1:]...)
// or
a = a[:i+copy(a[i:], a[i+1:])]
```

So basically it looks something like this:

```
c := appengine.NewContext(r)
// Constructing the key, for example:
k := datastore.NewKey(c, "Entity", "stringID", 0, nil)

e := datastore.PropertyList{}
if err = datastore.Get(c, key, &e); err != nil {
    // Datastore error.
    return
}

// Loop over the properties to find the one we want to remove:
for i, v := range e {
    if v.Name == "removeme" {
        // Found it!
        e = append(e[:i], e[i+1:]...)
        break
    }
}

if _, err = datastore.Put(c, k, &e); err != nil {
    // Datastore error
}
```

**Note:** Be careful when removing multiple elements from a slice using `for range`. Result might be unexpected as when you remove an element, all subsequent elements are shifted and you may skip an element. For details see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28699587/1705598).