# Delete an element from a slice does not work

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I want to delete some elements from a slice, but it does not work.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    for _, command := range a {
        if command == "a" || command == "b" || command == "c" {
            a = deleteSlice(a, command)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(a)
}
func deleteSlice(strings []string, str string) []string {
    out := strings[:0]
    for _, s := range strings {
        if s != str {
            out = append(out, s)
        }
    }
    return out
}
```

The expected result is `[]`,but it is `[b]`,actually.some people tell me the reason?

Comment: use this one for delete element from slice      append(slice[:s], slice[s+1:]...)

Comment: @Aibaend the way you post  only be work when delete one element.

Comment: use the loop for delete many elements

Comment: Ranging over a slice which is modified inside the loop is complicated and best avoided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *root* cause for the behavior is that inside `deleteSlice()`, you don't allocate a new backing array, you're reusing the backing array of the slice passed to it because you build the result in `strings[:0]`.

Slices have a backing array. In your code, there is a single allocation for such a backing array, in your composite literal when you initialize `a` which contains the elements:

```
array = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

So first `deleteSlice()` is called with `"a"`, which is in it, so it is not re-added. After the first iteration, backing array looks like this:

```
array = ["b", "c", "c"]
        [        ]               <- returned out slice covers this
```

The backing array still contains 3 elements, but the slice only covers the first 2.

The loop in main proceeds to the next iteration (index = 1), and the slice the loop iterates over covers the whole backing array (the slice used in `for rage` is only evaluated once!), so the element at index 1 in the backing array is now "c". This is passed to `deleteSlice()`. `deleteSlice()` removes the `"c"` element, backing array will not change (no elements to append after `"c"`):

```
array = ["b", "c", "c"]
        [   ]                    <- returned out slice covers this
```

and the returned slice has length 1 (the first element of the backing array.

The loop in main proceeds to the last iteration: index = 2. Backing array has element "c" at index 2, which is passed to `deleteSlice()`. This element is not containd in the slice (which covers a single `["b"]` element), so that is returned.

**See related questions:**

[Remove slice element within a for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495995/remove-slice-element-within-a-for/33496275#33496275)

[Remove elements in slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28699485/remove-elements-in-slice/28699587#28699587)

**Suggested readings:**

[The Go Blog: Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append'](https://blog.golang.org/slices)

[The Go Blog: Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

[Go Wiki: Slice tricks](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks)