# Golang remove elements when iterating over slice panics

Tags: go, slice

I want delete some elements from a slice, and https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks advise this slice-manipulation:

`a = append(a[:i], a[i+1:]...)`

Then I coded below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    slice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    for i, value := range slice {
        if value%3 == 0 { // remove 3, 6, 9
            slice = append(slice[:i], slice[i+1:]...)
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", slice)
}
```

with `go run hello.go`, it panics:

```
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x4ef680, 0xc082002040)
    D:/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:464 +0x3f4
main.main()
    E:/Code/go/test/slice.go:11 +0x395
exit status 2
```

**How can I change this code to get right?**

I tried below:

1st, with a `goto` statement:

```
func main() {
    slice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
Label:
    for i, n := range slice {
        if n%3 == 0 {
            slice = append(slice[:i], slice[i+1:]...)
            goto Label
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", slice)
}
```

it works, but too much iteration

2nd, use another slice sharing same backing array:

```
func main() {
    slice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    dest := slice[:0] 
    for _, n := range slice {
        if n%3 != 0 { // filter
            dest = append(dest, n)
        }
    }
    slice = dest
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", slice)
}
```

but not sure if this one is better or not.

3rd, from [Remove elements in slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28699485/remove-elements-in-slice), with `len` operator:

```
func main() {
    slice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    for i := 0; i < len(slice); i++ {
        if slice[i]%3 == 0 {
            slice = append(slice[:i], slice[i+1:]...)
            i-- // should I decrease index here?
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", slice)
}
```

which one should I take now?

with benchmark:

```
func BenchmarkRemoveSliceElementsBySlice(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        slice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
        dest := slice[:0]
        for _, n := range slice {
            if n%3 != 0 {
                dest = append(dest, n)
            }
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkRemoveSliceElementByLen(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        slice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
        for i := 0; i < len(slice); i++ {
            if slice[i]%3 == 0 {
                slice = append(slice[:i], slice[i+1:]...)
            }
        }
    }
}


$ go test -v -bench=".*"
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
BenchmarkRemoveSliceElementsBySlice-4   50000000                26.6 ns/op
BenchmarkRemoveSliceElementByLen-4      50000000                32.0 ns/op
```

it seems delete all elements in one loop is better

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Iterate over the slice copying elements that you want to keep.

```
k := 0
for _, n := range slice {
    if n%3 != 0 { // filter
        slice[k] = n
        k++
    }
}
slice = slice[:k] // set slice len to remaining elements
```

The slice trick is useful in the case where a single element is deleted. If it's possible that more than one element will be deleted, then use the for loop above.

[working playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/eMZltc_gEB)

Comment: In addition to this answer, it is more efficient to iterate over the entire array like this and populate a new one.  If you use simple primatives here, you'll actually get a hardware performance gain with prediction.  Read up on "Mechanical Sympathy" on coding, particularly in Go, to leverage CPU algorithms. While ur benchmark might not show much gain with on 9 numbers, try a few million to see the gains.

Comment: You saved me with this.

Answer (score 3):

while this is good answer for small slice:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    slice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

    k := 0
    for _, n := range slice {
        if n%3 != 0 { // filter
            slice[k] = n
            k++
        }
    }
    slice = slice[:k]

    fmt.Println(slice) //[1 2 4 5 7 8]
}
```

for **minimizing memory write** for first elements (for big slice), you may use this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    slice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

    k := 0
    for i, n := range slice {
        if n%3 != 0 { // filter
            if i != k {
                slice[k] = n
            }
            k++
        }
    }
    slice = slice[:k]

    fmt.Println(slice) //[1 2 4 5 7 8]
}
```

and if you need **new slice** or **preserving old slice**:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    slice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

    s2 := make([]int, len(slice))
    k := 0
    for _, n := range slice {
        if n%3 != 0 { // filter
            s2[k] = n
            k++
        }
    }
    s2 = s2[:k]

    fmt.Println(s2) //[1 2 4 5 7 8]
}
```

Comment: You can also do `if len(slice) != k` around `slice = slice[:k]` to prevent it from changing when not needed, if you care about that.